# custom themes didn't effect on buttons

Tags: android, android-button, android-theme

I have themes file to apply all of my buttons. The following coding is in my themes file.

```
    <style name="CustomButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button">
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">72dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">32dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_selector</item>
    </style>
   <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/CustomButton</item>
   </style>
```

In the @drawable/button_selector

```
<selector>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_bg">
        <shape>
            <size android:width="72dip" android:height="32dip"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#992f2f" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

In my layout file

```
<Button android:id="@+id/savebtn" 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Save"/>
```

My problem is that the button width and height didn't change. When I set layout_with(72dp) and layout_height(32dp) in the savebtn directly, it works. I have already defined themes file in application tag. I don't want to set all of my buttons like that. I would like to know any suggestions or idea?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myproject"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application 
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.setting.SettingActivity"
            android:label="@string/menu_settings" >
        </activity>
     <activity
            android:name=".activity.setting.AboutActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
         </activity>    
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.DetailsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
           <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
       </activity>      

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested exactly your code and it worked.

Did you add the following on your AndroidManifest.xml?

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
```

If still doesn't work, please post your manifest!

Also pay attention that if you are setting another theme on your activity, it will override the application theme!

Comment: yes I did. Does the button size change according to the size in button_selector?

Comment: Please post your AndroidManifest.xml!